# How to configure properties in ECMAScript 5: Object.create or Object.defineProperties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

What is the preferred way of defining property attributes in ECMAScript 5? From what I understand, there are at least two ways:

```
function Foo () {
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    'a': {
      value: "A",
      writable: false
    },
    'b': {
      value: "B",
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true
    }
  });
}

var f = new Foo();
```

Or:

```
var Foo = Object.create({}, {
    'a': {
      value: "A",
      writable: false
    },
    'b': {
      value: "B",
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true
    }
  });
};

var f = Object.create(Foo);
```

Besides the merits of instantiating with `new` vs `Object.create`, is there a performance hit in defining properties using `Object.defineProperties()`, as in the first example? Are the two equivalent? Is there a consensus on readability?

Comment: There's never consensus.

Comment: Regarding performance, it depends on the implementation and version. Test it.

Comment: Your constructor example is putting properties on `f`, while in your `Object.create` example, `f` is inheriting properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a performance hit in defining properties using `Object.defineProperties()`

Yes. Property descriptors are not optimized as normal properties and therefore much slower. If you (have to) use them, you don't care about performance anyway. Comparing `Object.create` with `new` is pretty meaningless due to their different behaviour and the insignificance of their performance divergence.

> Are the two equivalent?

No.

```
// The first one,
function Foo() {
    Object.defineProperties(this, propertydescriptors);
}
f = new Foo;
// is equivalent to
function Foo() {}
f = Object.defineProperties(new Foo, propertydescriptors);
// as long as there is closure in the property descriptor

// The second one,
foo = Object.create({}, propertydescriptors);
// is equivalent to
foo = Object.defineProperties(Object.create({}), propertydescriptors);
```

and `new Foo` is not the same as `Object.create({})` - there is no common `Foo.prototype`. Also, in your second example you even have

```
f = Object.create(foo);
```

which now is definitely different from the `f = new Foo` from above.

> Is there a consensus on readability?

The property descriptors in a constructor are quite uncommon. If you only need them, there is no reason not to use the shorter and more concise `Object.create` syntax. Yet, you should only use `Object.create` if you really want to inherit from something that is not the empty object:

```
f = Object.create(fooproto, propertydescriptors);
```

If not, just use

```
f = Object.defineProperties({}, propertydescriptors);
```